# Sort and Filter an object to show a Alphabetical list just like contacts in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs, filtering

I need to sort and filter an object as shown below...

```js
const companyList = {
  'A': ['apple','amazon','abiz','axios'],
  'B': ['bazinga','bob','biscount'],
  'C': ['Caterpillar','CastJ'],
};
```

Now i need the result to be sorted like

### **A**

apple, amazon, abiz, axios

### **B**

bazinga, bob, biscount

### **C**

caterpillar, castJ

and so on...
plus i need filtering as I search through the list

```js
import react,{PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const fruits = {
  'A': ['apple','amazon','abiz','axios'],
  'B': ['bazinga','bob','biscount'],
  'C': ['Caterpillar','CastJ'],
};

const fruitFilter = filter => fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

const Item = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    item: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  render() {
    return <span><li>{this.props.item}</li></span>;
  }
});

const ListContent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired
  },
  render() {
    const Items = this.props.items.map(item => <Item key={item} item={item} ></Item>);

    return <ul className="sort-advfilter-list-ul-div">{Items}</ul>;
  }
});

const AdvFilter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      filter: '',
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    let filteredFruits;
    let fru = [];
    for (var p in fruits) {
      if (fruits.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(fru,fruits[p]);

        filteredFruits = this.state.filter ?
          fru.filter(fruitFilter(this.state.filter)) :
          fru;
        console.log(p + " " + fruits[p]);
      }
    }

  return (<div className="sort-advfilter-scroll-div">
      <TextFilter onFilter={ ({target: {value: filter}} ) => this.setState({filter})}/>
      <ListContent items={filteredFruits}/>
    </div>
    )
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<AdvFilter />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you bump into when you try? Could you share your code and point out where it does not behave as expected?

Comment: @trincot you can see the snippet now

Comment: @trincot I think the component structure is blocking me to render as per requirement.

Comment: @TarangDave When you create a snippet, please make sure your code is running without errors. I have to add ending parenthesis to make it proper. Its still missing def for `propTypes`. Please resolve the issues in snippet

Comment: @Rajesh I understand